# Working set (private bytes) to get an idea for memory leaking process?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64

im using windows7 and trying to determine if my application process is leaking memory. i read about working set size and private bytes. In task manager private working set  is displayed. Is this a mixture of both?

what ist best value to determine a trend for leaks?

So far i used 'PagefileUsage' = private bytes 
and this value is slowly growing for my python script (python.exe)
my script also uses some c++ .dll's which i want to examine for leaking through python process.

How can i read WS private in python script? Seems its not part of GetProcessMemoryInfo() of win32api...

Comment: `my script also uses some c++ .dll's which i want to examine for leaking through python process.` - I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

Comment: there is a wrapper for this. but thats not so important. need to know the difference between Private bytes and Working set private bytes. how can i get WS private bytes? GetProcessMemoryInfo() from win32api does not help